# No podspec found for `flute_music_player` in `Pods/.symlinks/plugins/flute_music_player-0.0.6/ios`

Tags: flutter

when I compile the [flutter project](https://github.com/iampawan/Flutter-Music-Player.git) in my macOS Catalina 10.15.7, shows this error:

```
  Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro in debug mode...
Warning: Missing build name (CFBundleShortVersionString).
Warning: Missing build number (CFBundleVersion).
Action Required: You must set a build name and number in the pubspec.yaml file version field before submitting to the App Store.
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (`arm64`)

    Finding Podfile changes
      A flute_music_player
      R music_finder
      - Flutter

    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Pods/.symlinks/flutter/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `flute_music_player` from `Pods/.symlinks/plugins/flute_music_player-0.0.6/ios`
    [!] No podspec found for `flute_music_player` in `Pods/.symlinks/plugins/flute_music_player-0.0.6/ios`

    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb:14:in `block in fetch'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb:11:in `fetch'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:989:in `fetch_external_source'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:968:in `block (2 levels) in fetch_external_sources'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:967:in `each'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:967:in `block in fetch_external_sources'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:966:in `fetch_external_sources'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:117:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:414:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:239:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:238:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro.
```

where is going wrong and what should I do to fix it?  this is my environment info:

```
$ ~/apps/flutter/bin/flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H114 darwin-x64, locale en-CN)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.3)
```